# Setup up own STUN/TURN server or use Twilio STUN/TURN servers?

Tags: twilio, stun, turn, webrtc-android, videocall

I'm developing a video/voice call app that would be published on Play Store. I've set up the app, but I need to setup STUN/TURN servers.

Which solution would be **more effective** in terms of **handling traffic** and **cost**.

Using STUN/TURN serves provided by **Twilio**, Xirsys **or** setting up my **own servers**.

Could someone please help me understand which is the way to go?